# Execute task on hosts which match a pattern

Tags: deployment, fabric, glob

We use this pattern for our hosts (and linux users):

```
coreapp_customer_stageID@server
```

I want to run fabric commands on a list of hosts which match a pattern.

Example: I want to run "date" on all hosts of core app "foocms" of customer "c1".

I could use roles, but there are a lot of customers ... A glob matching way would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
@task
def set_hosts(lookup_param):
    '''
    '''
    hosts=get_all_systems() # that needs to be implemented by you.
    regex=re.compile('^%s' % lookup_param.replace('*', '.*'))
    sub_hosts=[host for host in hosts if regex.match(host)]
    if not sub_hosts:
        raise ValueError('No host matches %s. Available: %s' % (lookup_param, hosts))
    env.hosts = sub_hosts

@task
def date():
    run('date')
```

Example: `fab set_hosts:coreapp_customer1_* date`

Taken from: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/usage/execution.html#the-alternate-approach